# Integrity Error at /blog/2 NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_comment.post_id

Tags: django

I get an error when I try to add comments to my app.

**my form is:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'content'
        ]
```

**And the model is:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/'  , blank=True, null=True)
    # tags
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category'  ,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ' post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'posts'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ' category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'catogires'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name



class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content)
```

**my views are:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post , Category , Comment
from taggit.models import Tag
from .forms import CommentForm
def post_detail(request , id):
    post_detail = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    all_tags = Tag.objects.all()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post_detail)


    if request.method == 'POST' :
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.user = request.user
            new_comment.post = post_detail
            new_comment.save()

    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'post_detail' : post_detail ,
        'categories' : categories ,
        'all_tags' : all_tags ,
        'comments' : comments ,
        'comment_form' : comment_form
    }

    return render(request , 'Post/post_detail.html' , context)




def post_by_tag(request , tag):
    post_by_tag = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[tag])
    context = {
        'post_list' : post_by_tag ,
    }

    return render(request , 'Post/post_list.html' , context)
```

Please help me to solve the problem. I have checked several sources but I couldn't solve it. I found some similar codes that had written to add comments to posts specially in blogs and tried to use their method on my own code. But I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your method name and variable name are same:

```
def post_detail(request , id): # <-- Here
    post_detail = Post.objects.get(id=id) # <-- Here
```

Change the variable name to something else, like `post`

```
def post_detail(request , id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    all_tags = Tag.objects.all()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)


    if request.method == 'POST' :
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.user = request.user
            new_comment.post = post

    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'post_detail' : post ,
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: Please say what should I do? and whats the problem of that name

Comment: as I suggested in answer, please change `post_detail` variable name to something else.